# Cassandra ASP.NET Connection Pooling

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cassandra

I need to implement a connection pooling mechanism for a .Net 4.5 web application that uses [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) and [cassandra-sharp](https://github.com/pchalamet/cassandra-sharp) for data storage and data access respectively. I can see two standard options (ignoring Spring.Net for now):

- Implement the [System.Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.aspx) classes
- [COM+ Object Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff7105zk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

So:

1. What would you recommend? System.Data seems like a pain and a bit of a black box but COM+ seems legacy? Would Spring.Net [object pooling](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/pool.html) be a better option?
2. If I implement System.Data and use connection strings do I just work out which classes I need to implement by following the properties and methods in DbConnection? Or are there more setup stages e.g. special connection strings.
3. I need to ensure that there's strictly only ever a single reused connection in the pool and that it's capable of being accessed asynchronously. Is that a connection string setting for System.Data and is asynchronous access even possible with either approach?
4. There are large parts of System.Data that are relevant only to relational databases e.g. transactions. Which is least likely to break pooling when implementing not supported methods and properties: throwing a NotSupportedException or stubbing them?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [native driver](http://planetcassandra.org/DownLoad/ViewDownLoadType/datastax-c-client-driver-109)?  Seems like you're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I've not looked at the Datastax drivers recently but that one performed very poor when we started the project about 6 months ago. I suppose this is a good reference point though as there is now a Ado.Net driver in there. They do say 'This driver has not been released yet' though...

Comment: At this point the native driver is the best route, because the older drivers are based on the Thrift protocol, which has many drawbacks over the newer asynchronous binary protocol.